# MySQL Workbench data types

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I want to create or alter a table there is a nice GUI for that, but there are only 5 data types in the dropdown: INT, VARCHAR, DECIMAL, DATETIME, BLOB. What if I want to create, let's say, BIT ? I know I can copy the script and paste in the editor, change manually BLOB to BIT(1) and apply but if it is the only way then what is the sense of having GUI tool for altering table?
I use version 8.0.17 for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual for macOS you don't see that an area is scrollable, if you set your scrollbars to hide automatically (happens when you have a touchpad attached). Try to scroll the data type drop down to see more options:

[image]